# How to fix noClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.facebook

Tags: android

Integrating facebook sdk with android app.before integrating app working fine but once working with facebook app stopped unexpectedly here i am placing the code.suggest me how to fix this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btnTOLogin, btnTOPost, logOut;
    String APP_ID;
    Facebook fb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        APP_ID = "308180782571605";
        fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);

        try {
            btnTOLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btnTOPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            logOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            btnTOLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnTOPost.setOnClickListener(this);
            logOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

here logs

```
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at com.sri.z4globalsoft.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-15 22:08:52.531: E/AndroidRuntime(2151):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export and make sure facebook library is ticked.

Comment: it is ticked but having same problem.

Comment: Are you sure you add the external jar in your project ?

Comment: external jar?i am using facebook library project.it is added in build path

Comment: Project -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jar -> facebook.jar

Answer (score 0):

clean the project..|
go to libs folder select facebookjar right click and select add to build path
(or) Java Build Path -> Order & Export and make sure facebook library is ticked.
some times it depends on order of libraries in order and export move up and down check it may come